# rsync not deleting files

Tags: rsync

OS is Debian 12, rsync version 3.2.7.

I've been using rsync to make nightly backups like so:

```
rsync -ar --info=progress2 --delete /mnt/data/ /mnt/backup_data
```

This doesn't actually delete any files however, and now my backup drive is out of space. `/mnt/data` and `/mnt/backup_data` have identical capacity.

What am I doing wrong? How do I simply tell rsync "dest should contain all files and dirs exactly the same as src, make it happen via deltas" ?

Comment: Are you getting space-related errors while running the command? Try adding `--delete-before` to the command's arguments to ensure that the data that should be deleted is deleted before transferring new data to the destination.  Also, since you are doing a local sync, the delta algorithm will not kick in (it would be inefficient, so it's only used over networks).  And lastly, `-a` implies `-r`, so `-ar` could be changed to just `-a`.

Comment: Hi cat pants, you don't seem to have accepted any of the answers to your previous questions, and you haven't reacted to my comment of yesterday to your previous question. Maybe slow down and do one thing after the other! That includes telling the people that tired to help you whether they solved your problem, or whether you solved it yourself.